# Sort array of objects by text (not alphabetically -, 'easiest' to 'hardest')

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects with a difficulty property and I want to be able to sort the list by 'easiest' to 'hardest' where the possible values are 'easiest', 'easy', 'medium', 'hard' and 'hardest'. To sort alphabetically by title I simply do something like:

```js
items.sort((a, b) => ((b.title > a.title) ? 1 : -1));
```

but this will not give the desired results for 'easiest to hardest'. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please add your array also.

Comment: Why are you using `.title` if the property is named `difficulty`?

Comment: I was just giving an example of what I tried / did with title. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a map from string to int:

```
const sortMap = {
   'easiest': 0,
   'easy': 1,
   'medium': 2,
   'hard': 3,
   'hardest': 4,
}
// and then sort with it
items.sort((a, b) => (sortMap[b.difficulty] - sortMap[a.difficulty]);
```

This might be a bit more faster then using `indexOf`, but it's a bit error prone, since you have to be cautious assigning the values to the key in the map object

Answer (score 2):

Put all the possible titles in an array and sort by their indexes in the array.

```
const levels = ['easiest', 'easy', 'medium', 'hard', 'hardest'];
items.sort((a, b) => levels.indexOf(b.difficulty) - levels.indexOf(a.difficulty));
```